# html custom element, slot content appended after #shadow-root

Tags: javascript, html, pug, shadow-dom

i try to create custom element with js. this is my custom element

```
class ImageBackground extends HTMLElement {
  createdCallback() {
    let src = this.hasAttribute('src') ? this.getAttribute('src') : '/static/images/user.png'
    let className = `img-bg ${this.hasAttribute('className') ? this.getAttribute('className') : ''}`
    let isLazy = this.getAttribute('lazy') !== false

    const slotContent = document.createElement('slot')
    slotContent.setAttribute('name', 'slot-content')

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div')
    wrapper.appendChild(slotContent)
    wrapper.style.backgroundImage = `url("${src}")`
    wrapper.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
    wrapper.style.backgroundPosition = 'center'
    wrapper.style.height = '300px'
    wrapper.setAttribute('class', className)

    this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(wrapper)
  }
}

document.registerElement('img-bg', ImageBackground)
```

and this is my pug template

```
img-bg(src="/static/images/email.svg")
      p(slot="slot-content") cek
```

i want to append p element inside the slot. but the p element appended after the #shadow-root.

[image]

can anyone solve this... :( sorry for the bad english

Comment: note: you are mixing Shadow DOM v0 (createShadowRoot) and Shadow DOM v1 syntax (<slot>). I'm not sure that could work. You'd rather use attachShadow (Shadow DOM v1) method to create your Shadow DOM. Also, use Custum Element v1 syntax insread of v0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<slot>` tag is used to *import* children of the element into the `<slot>` and not a place for you to put your own children.

The best you could do is to wrap your `<slot>` in something else and then place the component's `<p>` tag just after the `<slot>`.

**Alternatively, and not recommended:**

If you want to add any tag, generated by the component, into the slot then you need to place the tag as a child of your element and not into the shadowDOM. As long as it is placed as a proper child, matching the requirements of the `<slot>` than it should show in the `<slot>`.

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML = `
    <style>
      .wrapper {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      ::slotted(*) {
        background-color: #8F8; 
        margin: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <p>Before Slot</p>
    <div class="wrapper"><slot>Hi There</slot></div>
    <p>After Slot</p>
    `;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
  }
}

customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);

function addChild() {
  var el = document.querySelector('my-el');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = "New stuff as a child.";
  el.appendChild(p);
}

var button = document.querySelector('#one');
button.addEventListener('click', addChild);
```

```css
p {
  font-family: tahoma;
}

my-el p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Before Element</p>
<my-el>
  <p>Stuff in the slot</p>
</my-el>
<p>After Element</p>
<hr/>
<button id="one">Add Child</button>
```

So the only way to add into the slot is to add child elements to the element.

> That is probably not a good thing to do since you are altering the content that the user of your component created. And that could mess up their code, CSS or both.

Answer (score 1):

`<slot>` is defined in Shadow DOM v1. Therefore you mus use [`attachShadow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow) instead of `createShadowRoot()`:

```
this.attachShadow({ mode:'open'}).appendChild(wrapper)
```